# Create remote git repo on visual studio team server (or gitlab) using visual studio code

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I'm curious if we can create a remote git repository on vsts or gitlab from visual studio code editor? (by default or by using any plugin?).

I want to avoid signing in to the online website just to create a repo.

Thanks. Any guidance in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any plugin that does this but you could [create a custom git command](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/extending-git) that use the [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project) to create the remote repo and configure your local one to work with it.